# Get the first and last day of a year from a timestamp

Tags: time, go

Given a time object, `t := time.Now()`, is there a way I could get a timestamp for the first and last days of that year?

I could do something like `d := t.YearDay()` to get the number of days through the year, and then `t.AddDate(0, 0, -d)` to get the start of the year, and `t.AddDate(0, 0, 365-d)` to get the end of the year, but that seems to brittle as it doesn't deal with leap years etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use your Time struct object and create new Time struct object using [time.Date](http://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=29954:30037#L1011) and [time.Time.Year()](http://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=10009:10033#L286) functions. So, if current time is `t := time.Now()` then last day in this year in UTC will be `lt := time.Date(t.Year(), time.December, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)`

Here's an example:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    t := time.Now()
    last := time.Date(t.Year(), time.December,31, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    first := time.Date(t.Year(), time.January,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)

    fmt.Println("Current: ", t)
    fmt.Println("First: ", first)
    fmt.Println("Last: ", last)

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/jahjd_mi6K